# Some question on defining the space of graph homology for Jacobi diagrams

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, graph-theory, homology, holomorphic-symplectic, hyperkaehler

I read Chapter 2.1 "The space of graph homology" from Nieper-Wißkirchen's *Chern Numbers and Rozansky-Witten Invariants of Compact Hyper-Kähler Manifolds* today, and have some question. I'm not sure if this question would be better suited for mathSE, because it is rather basic.

First recall the definitions: A Jacobi diagram is an undirected graph (possibly with multiple edges) where all vertices have degree $1$ or $3$, and all $3$-valent vertices have a prescribed orientation. A vertex of degree $1$ is called a leg, and a marking is a bijection the set of legs to some finite set $I$.

For any such finite set $I$, we denote by $\mathcal J_I$ the free $k[\circ]$-module, generated by isomorphism classes of Jacobi diagrams marked over $I$. Here $k[\circ]$ is just considered as a polynomial ring over a field $k$ of characteristic $0$. (To prevent set-theoretic issues, one has to fix some infinite sets $\mathfrak F$ and $\mathfrak I$, and only consider $I \subset \mathfrak I$ and Jacobi diagrams with vertices in $\mathfrak F$).

Questions:

1. I'm not sure if I understand the definition of "subspace" correctly.

> **Definition** By a *subspace* $(A_I)_I$ *of the space of Jacobi diagrams* we mean a subspace $A_I$ of $\mathcal J_I$ for every finite set $I$ such that for every bijection $\phi: I \to J$, we have $\phi_*(A_I) = A_J$.

Does that mean that $A_I \subset \mathcal J_I$ is subset, a subgroup or even a $k[\circ]$-submodule? Later he seems to consider quotients $\mathcal J_I / A_I$, at least if $(A_I)_I$ is an ideal, so my guess is we want some algebraic structure on $A_I$?

2. The ideal $\operatorname{AS}$ is defined to be the ideal generated by $\Gamma_+ + \Gamma_-$, where $\Gamma_+$ is the marked Jacobi diagram over $\{1,2,3\}$ which consists of one 3-valent vertex and three legs, marked in clockwise order. $\Gamma_-$ is the same Jacobi diagram marked counter-clockwise. So the anti-symmetry relation reads

[image]

He then writes

> The anti-symmetry relation says that changing the orientation of one trivalent vertex is equal to changing the sign in $\mathcal J_I / \operatorname{AS}$.

As an example he writes that in $\mathcal J_{\{1\}} / AS$, we have

[image]

I see that changing the orientation gives the same Jacobi diagram, but I cannot apply $\operatorname{AS}$ here. Informally, the ideal $\operatorname{AS}$ is generated by an element of degree $3$ with respect to the "number of legs"-grading. Formally, the ideal $(A_I)_I$ given by $A_{\emptyset} = 0, A_I = 0$ for all $\# I = 1$ and $A_I = \mathcal J_I$ for all $\# I \geq 2$ is an ideal that contains $\operatorname{AS}$, proving $\mathcal J_{\{1\}} / \operatorname{AS} = \mathcal J_{\{1\}}$.

So what would be the correct definition of $\operatorname{AS}$? Do we want to include changing the orientation for any trivalent vertex?

3. Is it correct that we identify the formal multiplication by $\circ \in k[\circ]$ with taking the disjoint union with the graph "$\circ$", which is the graph with empty set of vertices?
4. This is only a question of notation: Is there any difference in the following three Jacobi diagrams?

[image]

I can see the educational value for using the first one, when explaining that we allow crossings in our diagrams (because four-valent vertices are not allowed anyway). But wouldn't it be more consistent to stick with one of them?